# How to make a single id for a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new to javascript but putting my all efforts I have written a javascript to copy the text inside the `<p></p>`. But according to my javascript I need to keep different id for different `<p></p>` elements. For reference

```
function copyToClipboard(var1, btn){
  let val = document.getElementById(var1).innerHTML;
  const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
  selBox.style.left = '0';
  selBox.style.top = '0';
  selBox.style.opacity = '0';
  selBox.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  selBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  let item = btn.parentNode.querySelector(".invisible");
  if (item) {
      item.classList.remove("invisible");
      setTimeout(function() {
          item.classList.add("invisible");
      }, 400);
  }
}
```

My Html

```
  <div class="Engstatus">
   <h2 class="statusheading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="englishstatus">
       <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p9">life os good when hou have books</p> 
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p9', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p10">Google is a open source library. It is a open source by lary page and sergy brime</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p10', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p11">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p11', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p12">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard('p12', this)">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

My Css

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
    animation: slideInFromRight 1s ease-in;
}
.copystatusalert{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, margin-top 0.4s;
  text-align: center;
```

My Css is for reference purposes. PLZZ help mr am stuck here from a week and tired of searching for results. And mainly thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't really use document.execCommand anymore. I don't have too much time right now to make an answer, but to copy to clipboard: use `navigator.clipboard.writeText('stuff')`

Comment: Why do you want to make single ID ? Explain little more about what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem in that

Answer (score 0):

So what is the question? What is the problem exactly? Sounds like you've answered your own question and you aren't sure what you want to do instead?

In the DOM an elements id needs to be unique - this isn't something you can change, using the same id for multiple elements is not valid HTML.

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

returns a single element. If there are multiple elements in the DOM with the same id it will only return the first one.

If the id's of your element are the same and you use document.getElementById, how is it supposed to know whether you want the first, second, or third?

Since you're passing "this" into the function, you could instead get the parent of the passed in element, then search that parent element for the p element and get it's inner text.

```
this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent
```

This assumes there's only going to be one paragraph element and that your layout is going to be consistently as you've shown it here.

Alternatively use the default event:

```
function copyToClipboard(event){
  let val = event.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent;
  const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
  selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
  selBox.style.left = '0';
  selBox.style.top = '0';
  selBox.style.opacity = '0';
  selBox.value = val;
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  selBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  let item = btn.parentNode.querySelector(".invisible");
  if (item) {
      item.classList.remove("invisible");
      setTimeout(function() {
          item.classList.add("invisible");
      }, 400);
  }
}
```

```
 <div class="Engstatus">
   <h2 class="statusheading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="englishstatus">
       <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p9">life os good when hou have books</p> 
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p10">Google is a open source library. It is a open source by lary page and sergy brime</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p11">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="latestatus">
     <p id="p12">Cat is better than dog</p>
     <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="copyToClipboard">Copy</button>
       <span class="copystatusalert invisible">Copied!</span>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Update: To avoid having to set the onClick in the html, you can do it by javascript:

```
const buttons = document.getElementByClassName("copystatus");
for (const button in buttons) {
  button.onClick = copyToClipboard;
}
```

This assumes the "copystatus" class will only be on those buttons, otherwise you'd need to derive your own selector which will resolve just the buttons you want.

Comment: Please make it available with class. And make it so that I don't need to write onclick every time.

Comment: I've added an update on how to set the onClick via javascript instead of the html, if you have additional questions I would recommend raising them separately.